# angular ui bootstrap on page load not popping up

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

I trying to pop up a modal on page load. I can see the response and html in the firebug console but there is no popup thats displayed.

Installed ui-bootstrap

Added in the app.js

```
angular.module('sample', ['ui.router','angular-clipboard','ui.bootstrap'])
```

Modal.html

```
<div id="modal" class="bx--modal" tabindex="-1">
<div class="bx--modal-container">
    <div class="bx--modal-content">
        <div class="bx--modal-header">
            <button class="bx--modal-close" type="button" data-modal-close>X</button>
            <h4 class="bx--modal-header__heading">Subscribe our Newsletter</h4>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.myDialog = function () {
    $modal.open({
       templateUrl: 's***/p*/v**/p**/modal.html',
       backdrop: 'static',
       windowClass: 'modal',
       size: 'lg',
       controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.cancel = function () {
               $modalInstance.dismiss();
            };
          }
    });
};
```

Called the function in html page on whose load I want a modal popup to be displayed automatically as:

```
<span ng-init="myDialog()"></span>
```

There are no errors in firebug console. I can see the modal.html in the response and also the page in HTML. But there is no popup.
[image]

[image]

The pop up doesnt show on page load even though the modal.html is fetched properly. Where am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to load a modal automatically on page load?

Comment: Works fine here: https://plnkr.co/edit/zAwCCrThWUawrDIaa4mc?p=preview. Without a complee example reproducing the problem, it's hard to help. Also, the fact that you're using $modal instead of $uibModal shows that you're using a very old version of ui bootstrap. That's something you should fix first: old versions = old bugs.

Comment: I tried with $uibModal  but it gives $injector:unpr error

Comment: That's because you're still using your old version of ui-bootstrap. My point is that you should migrate to the latest version.

Comment: The current version is 2.5.2. There have been 31 released since 0.14.3. It came out in 2015.